# android wallpaper image path

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, wallpaper

I need to get the path of the image currently serving as a background image in the wallpaper.

I managed to get the bitmap itself (using the drawable from the wallpaper manager) - but i dont need the drawable- i need the path so i can save it in sharedpreferences and use it later.

```
final WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
final Bitmap wallpaperBitmap =drawableToBitmap(wallpaperDrawable);
```

btw, according to [The wallpapermanager's manual](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) i cant use getWallpaperInfo since it will return null if its not a live wallpaper.

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code

```
Drawable wallpaper = peekWallpaper();
final Bitmap wallpaperBitmap =drawableToBitmap(wallpaper);
```

and for absolute path follow this https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27709